# Removing negation of a variable

Tags: python, list

I am working on Boolean expression problem in python where I am trying to eliminate the variable and it's negation. I have created two separate lists but do not know how to delete the elements which are opposite.

For eg:

```
a = ['~A','~B','~C']
b = ['B','C']
```

I want the output to be '~A'....
Tried many things but no luck.

Comment: Show what you have tried, then we can see where you may be having issues.

Comment: For each element `e` in `b`, filter out `e` and `'~' + e` from `a`

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question: This looks like an interesting question, what's it for?

Comment: Can there be negated values in `b`, or only in `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Create negation list of `b`. E.g. b=['B', 'C', '~D'], negations=['~B', '~C', 'D']
- Create an empty list `c`
- Loop through `a`, if an item is not in `negations`, append it to `c`
- Return `c`

```py
negations = [el.lstript("~") if el.startwith("~") else "~%s" % el for el in b]
result = [el for el in a if el not in negations]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the negation prefix, then check if the value is in `b`.

```
result = [el for el in a if el.lstrip('~') not in b]
```

Comment: For the input `a = ['~A','~B','C'] b = ['B','~C']`, the 'result', I get from the above code is `['~A', 'C']`. I think the 'result' for this input should be `['~A']`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The example doesn't show negated values in `b`, so I assumed there wouldn't be.